# "Duplicate symbol" when attempting to compile two .cpp files (from XCode) in terminal (MacOSX)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, g++

I have two .cpp files, main.cpp and secondFile.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "I was also able to add this line!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This was from the second file!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have successfully run `g++ -o main.cpp main` and `g++ -o secondFile.cpp secondFile`, as well as run each of their corresponding executables. However when I attempt to compile them simultaneously into a single executable `g++ -o main.cpp secondFile.cpp bothScripts` or `clang++ main.cpp secondFile.cpp -o bothScripts` I receive the following error:

"duplicate symbol _main in:
    /var/folders/49/38grlkzs44zcth3v_dw9m9dm0000gn/T/main-d43536.o
    /var/folders/49/38grlkzs44zcth3v_dw9m9dm0000gn/T/secondfile-2bee63.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Clearly something is being loaded twice, but I am unsure whether this is a library (iostream), that I've named both sections 'main', or something else entirely. There are certainly questions similar to this already, but many are convoluted and not as fundamental for new C++ members (hence my question here).

Context: My rationale is to practice building executables from multiple .cpp files. Is there a better way to go about this? (New to C++ but not to programming/code as a whole.)

Comment: You cannot have more than one `main()` entry point in an executable.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So what should I change in the second script to compile them simultaneously? By changing 'main' to 'second' for example, I can successfully compile them together, but only the code from the first script will run and print.

Comment: If you cange the function name to `second()` you have to call it explicitely from the remaining `main()` function to run it. Don't forget to forward declare `second()` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is simple. You have 2 `main()` functions. As you should know, in a C++ program, the function `main()` generally defines the entry point of a program. When each of the files are compiled together, and have their own `main()` function, the compiler gets confused and throws an error. To solve this, simply change the name of the `main()` function in one file, and call it from the other file, if you are planning to run them together.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! After changing 'main' in secondFile, how then can I call it from the first script? Would I then only use `g++ -o main.cpp` or would I still use `g++ -o main.cpp secondFile.cpp`?

Comment: For example, if your new function was called `func`, then go in your `main()` function, and at the end of it before the `return 0;`, add the line `func();`. For running this, use `g++ -o main.cpp secondFile.cpp exec_name`. In addition, you will have to forward declare the function `func`, before `main()`, with something like `int func();`. Last but not least, if you found this answer helpful, don't forget to mark it correct, so that it can help future users gain knowledge and not ask the same question multiple times!